# Port forwarding a Debian OwnCloud server: not working

Tags: debian, port-forwarding, owncloud, untangle

I recently set up an [OwnCloud](https://owncloud.org/) server with **Apache2 on Debian 8.2 Jessie**. I installed Debian first (of course), then Apache2 and then OwnCloud with **MySQL**. The program works perfectly within the network and runs on the Static IP address **192.168.1.16**. I have forwarded the port **8080** (and told Apache to listen there) through my router (router's default gateway is through an Untangle server - Captive Portal and Firewall are disabled).

Port 8080 works fine (and so does **80** when Apache is set to that) from inside the network but it doesn't work at all from the outside. I have tried using my mobile network with no success. My router is a **TP-Link TD-W9980**.

I use Sky as my ISP and they do not block any ports. Port checkers say that the only port open is 1194 (for Untangle remote admin). 8080 and 80 are not open.

Comment: What is your router WAN interface IP? Maybe you are behind [carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT).

Comment: What is my WAN Interface IP? knetwork.ddns.net is my DDNS site

Comment: I'm not familiar with "untangle server" as a gateway, but a quick Google shows it filters and firewalls. You may need to open a port at do a second forwarding on that server.

Comment: What port should I open? Untangle is currently not filtering with it's firewall.

Comment: If you're forwarding 8080 on the router and there is another firewall ahead of the router you would need to open port 8080 on that firewall.